# How do I keep a HTML element fixed at a position?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to create a portfolio in which when the user scrolls, a small bar icon is visible and fixed. On clicking, it should display the tools in navigation bar like "about me, contact me".

I tried using position: fixed; but it isn't working.

and I can't seem to get this bar icon to the left side of the page. Tried giving it different margin and padding and the drop down isn't working either.

```css
.fa { 
 transform: scale(0.5,0.5); 
}

.dropdown{
 
 position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle pull-left" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.dropdown not must be child another elem, except body

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown{
  position: fixed;
}
```

Example:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  
  height: 200vh;
  background: linear-gradient(orange 0, red 50%, pink 100%);
}
.dropdown{
  position: fixed;
  
  width: 140px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
</div>
```